# How to count unique value from object of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-push

I want to calculate number of unique value and put that in new array.
I have below array:

```
[
  { CategoryId: "b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1", CategoryColor: "cgreen" }
  { CategoryId: "9872cce5af92", CategoryName: "Category 2", CategoryColor: "purple" }
  { CategoryId: "b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1", CategoryColor: "cgreen" }
]
```

I want new array with below result:

```
[
    { CategoryId: "b5c3f43f941c", count: 2, CategoryColor: "cgreen" }
    { CategoryId: "9872cce5af92", count: 1, CategoryColor: "purple" }
]
```

In this check by id, if id is same show count and new in new array.

Hope you understand what I want.

Thanks,

Comment: For any lodash users here: (_.uniqBy(arrayOfObjects, 'propertyName')).length

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can loop through array using "for..of" and create a temporary object to save data in every loop. If same id exists in tempObject then increment count by 1

```js
var arr = [
  { CategoryId: "b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1", CategoryColor: "cgreen" }
  , { CategoryId: "9872cce5af92", CategoryName: "Category 2", CategoryColor: "purple" }
  , { CategoryId: "b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1", CategoryColor: "cgreen" }
]

var tempResult = {}

for(let { CategoryColor, CategoryId } of arr)
  tempResult[CategoryId] = { 
      CategoryId, 
      CategoryColor, 
      count: tempResult[CategoryId] ? tempResult[CategoryId].count + 1 : 1
  }      

let result = Object.values(tempResult)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `reduce` function and inside the callback check an object exist whose `CategoryId` matches. If matches then update the count or else create a new object with the values and push in the array

```js
let k = [{
    CategoryId: "b5c3f43f941c",
    CategoryName: "Category 1",
    CategoryColor: "cgreen"
  },
  {
    CategoryId: "9872cce5af92",
    CategoryName: "Category 2",
    CategoryColor: "purple"
  },
  {
    CategoryId: "b5c3f43f941c",
    CategoryName: "Category 1",
    CategoryColor: "cgreen"
  }
]

let result = k.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  // Check if there exist an object in empty array whose CategoryId matches
  let isElemExist = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.CategoryId === curr.CategoryId;
  })
  if (isElemExist === -1) {
    let obj = {};
    obj.CategoryId = curr.CategoryId;
    obj.count = 1;
    obj.CategoryColor = curr.CategoryColor;
    acc.push(obj)
  } else {
    acc[isElemExist].count += 1
  }
  return acc;

}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/S%E1%BA%AFp_x%E1%BA%BFp) the array first then count the duplicates. The downside is it will modify the original `yourArray` due to being sorted, so use with caution.

```
yourArray.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.CategoryName > b.CategoryName) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.CategoryName < b.CategoryName) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

var pivot = yourArray[0];
pivot.count = 0;
var counted = [pivot];
yourArray.forEach(item => {
  if (item.CategoryId === pivot.CategoryId) {
    pivot.count++;
  } else {
    pivot = item;
    pivot.count = 1;
    counted.push(pivot);
  }
});
```

Comment: "The downside is it will modify the original yourArray due to being sorted, so use with caution."  - i read about this recently:  https://2ality.com/2022/04/change-array-by-copy.html   -- i think its `toSorted()` - might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

```
const array_unique = require('array-hyper-unique').array_unique

let arr = [
  { CategoryId: "b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1", CategoryColor: "cgreen" }
  { CategoryId: "9872cce5af92", CategoryName: "Category 2", CategoryColor: "purple" }
  { CategoryId: "b5c3f43f941c", CategoryName: "Category 1", CategoryColor: "cgreen" }
]

array_unique(arr).length
```